# Want to get a every word entered in the input string in next line

Tags: python-3.x

```
x = int(input("How many times you want the print :"))

if x>0 :
    a = str(input("Enter the string: ""\n" ))
    d = x * a 

    print(d)
else:
    print("dont know")
```

#for example:
How many times you want the print: 3
Enter the string:Aman Singh

#output i want should be : Aman
Singh
Aman
Singh
Aman
Singh

Comment: it should show Aman then in next line Singh, vertically

Comment: I tested the code and it works fine, if the output that you show in the question is really what you want.  But the question is confusing because your title states something different. However, if what you show is what you want, the only thing missing was the space so you might want to add that in which I fixed with this:  `d = x * (a+' ')`  But this will leave a space after it which you can trim/strip at the end if you want with: `(x * (a+' ')).strip()`